# i have create project with the help of xib( load xib) and now i want to add storyboard in particular button tab and open storyboard

Tags: swift

```
let storyboard = self.storyboard!
let storyCtrl  = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginTableViewController")
self.presentViewController(storyCtrl, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
```

I am getting this error : - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: Please add more detail about self.storyboard, did you initialized this variable before using it?

Comment: Can you show us how did you initialized `self.storyboard`?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0** Use the following code to load controller from story board

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController")
self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
```

**Main** = name of the storyboard

**viewController** = the name of the view controller identifier